# How to determine number of DBUs used in Azure Databricks?

Tags: azure, databricks

I have been trying to calculate the cost of my job run in trial version of Azure Databricks, however i cant find out how many DBUs are getting utilised for the function.
Please suggest some ways.
Thanks

I also tried looking up logs and metrics of the run, however I couldnt understand a single thing.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75810798/1305344) seems related

Answer (score 0):

The only know option to me is using the build-in `system.billing.usage` table, that's currently in preview. This table is stored on unity catalog and isn't enabled by default. To enable it you need at least one unity catalog enabled databricks workspace.

Setting up unity catalog requires a bit more effort and Account level configuration. If you haven't setup unity catalog yet instructions can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/get-started).

To enable this build-in table you have to follow [this instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/system-tables/#list-available-system-schemas).

Basically you have to run this API request:

```bash
curl -v -X PUT -H "Authorization: Bearer <DATABRICKS_PAT_TOKEN>" "https://adb-<XXX>.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/unity-catalog/metastores/<UNITY_CATALOG_METASTORE_ID>/systemschemas/billing"
```

After enabling the `billing` table you can use the following SQL Query to get the number of used DBUs of the last month.

```
SELECT SUM(usage_quantity) AS `DBUs`
FROM system.billing.usage
WHERE
    MONTH(usage_date) = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, NOW()))
    AND YEAR(usage_date) = YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, NOW()));
```

More sample queries can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/system-tables/billing#sample-queries).